# Need clarification on the Azure Functions ecosystem

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am having a hard time understand the current set of options and components currently available (January 2019) to us with respect to `Azure Functions`. Part of my issue could also be what is seemingly confusing terminology and/or versioning and what seems like very stale documentation (many of the pages listed here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics) are still dated from 2017.).

As I understand it

- There is the original **Version 1** of Azure Functions which allows you to run code snippets targeting `.NET Full Framework`
- There is the newer **Version 2** of Azure Functions which allows you to run code snippets targeting `.NET Standard / Core`. This was in beta (??), preview (??) last year and went **GA** around September / October 2018?
- All new features will be targeted at version 2 of the Function Runtime (??)
- There is a **UI Portal** (??) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-runtime-install and https://aka.ms/azafrv2) that is labeled as **Preview 2** which *seems* to be from November 2017. Interestingly, it **does** provide the option of running both **v1** and **v2** Azure Functions on-premise.

  - Cannot seem to find a newer version of this portal. This post (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/15820#issuecomment-427089585) states there are no plans to update the Portal. Does this mean that MS is abandoning running Azure Functions on-premise?
  - I am guessing that the Runtimes bundled in the Portal site are from 2017 and not running the latest runtimes?
- Unsure what the relationship is between `Azure Webjobs SDK`, `Azure Functions Host`, `WebJobs Script`, `Azure Core Tools`, and`Azure Functions Runtime`.

Ultimately, I am looking to run Azure Functions on-premise and need to support both **v1** and **v2**. While the vast majority of functions we are going to create will target the newer v2, we have two or three .NET libraries that have yet to be ported away from Full Framework and since they are 3rd party, we cannot control the time frame.)

Ideally we would like to provide a on-premise Portal for developers to upload the functions from Visual Studio or even create them via the browser.

Even better would be to containerize the functions and run them in an on-premise Azure Service Fabric. (I realize this is advanced and probably beyond the scope of this posting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conclude your questions to 3 points

1. Runtime difference(The first three items)

   Your understanding is totally right that V1 targeting Full NetFramework and V2 on .NET Core, which is announced to be GA since 9/24/2018. And yes, all new features will be only targeted at V2.
2. The relationship between those terms(The 5th item).

   [Azure Webjobs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk#azure-webjobs-sdk) is a framework that simplifies the task of writing background processing code that runs in Azure. In .NET functions, it(along with Webjobs extensions) is referenced by `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`.

   [WebJobs.Script](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host#webjobsscript) = Azure Functions host = Azure Functions Runtime, where our functions work. It's built upon Azure WebJobs SDK and enables a light-weight scripting model for it, the scripting library does the work necessary to plug our function scripts into the Azure WebJobs SDK runtime.

   [Azure Functions Core Tools(CLI)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#azure-functions-core-tools) is a command line tool integrated with Azure Functions Runtime. Our local development(e.g. running, debugging) depends on this tool.
3. Azure Functions Runtime preview 2(The 4th item)

   It offers a UI similar to Azure Function portal and consumes very old Function runtime from [obsolete docker hub image](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker/issues/8#issuecomment-387595921). As you have found in the [thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/15820#issuecomment-427089585), no plan to update, not sure whether it will be abandoned or not.

   So far we are not able to get a working on-premises Portal and could only turn to CLI or container for local running. Note that there's No image for v1 function. Not familiar with Azure Service Fabric so no more suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for the response Jerry. If I understand what you stated correctly, and some other things I have read elsewhere, _conceptually_ we could most likely (definitely ??) run our **v2** Azure Functions on-prem on container servers (built-in to Windows OS, Kebernetes, Azure Service Fabric, etc.) and let those platforms orchestrate deployment and running? As far as **v1** Functions go (for those few legacy libraries I need to support) we _may_ be able to do the same with that obsolete docker image (but obviously unsupported)?

Comment: @Jason Totally correct, v2 functions are easy to work with docker container, e.g. CLI has commands to deploy function to kubernetes. As for v1, the image is only used for the `Functions Runtime preview` and too old to work with v1 functions today.

Comment: Hi, @Jason Any progress? Could you accept the answer if it is a reasonable explanation?